# CZT: Do Bluestein algorithm perform backward transformation?

Tags: fft, chirp

I am in discussion with one of my colleague that he says changing sign of the exponent in [Bluestein's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chirp_Z-transform#Bluestein%27s_algorithm) for Chirp-Z transformation, transforms the spectrum from frequency to time domain?

I am sort of confused, since they have invented ICZT very recently and it works in a different way.

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/77156/230294) on using Chirp Z-transform (CZT) to calculate DFT will be useful to you.

Comment: Yes. My colleague used the same algorithm and instead of time-samples he use frequency-samples at the input and changed the sign in the exponent to get the samples back in time-domain. I don't really agree with that since ICZT is totally different, which is explained in this article 
https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-019-50234-9.pdf

Comment: Maybe he meant calculating inverse discrete Fourier transform (IDFT) using CZT?

Comment: Yes. He calculates inverse discrete Fourier transform with Bluestein algorithm. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to calculate IDFT using DFT, by applying the property:

$$\operatorname{IDFT}(x) = \frac{1}{N}\big(\operatorname{DFT}(x^*)\big)^*,\tag{1}$$

where $^*$ denotes elementwise complex conjugation. You can find this equation in a more verbose form in Eq. 13-55 of Richard G. Lyons "Understanding Digital Signal Processing" 3rd edition.

Probably this was used along with conjugation properties of the exponential.